# Rails translating run-time models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use a 'run-time' model which is not inherited from ActiveRecord class:

```
class Forms::Contact
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :content

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

But in this case how can I organize my localization yml files to be able to automatically translate the attributes like ActiveRecords?

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: Name
        email: E-mail
        password: Password
        password_confirmation: Password confirmation
        current_password: Current password
        remember_me: Remember me
        role: Role
      forms/contact:
        name: Name
        content: Message
```

So in this case the translation will not work, cause the contact is not an active record, I think.
Are there any good yml "organization" to the attributes of run-time models will be automatically translated?

Of course I can use the classic way with the `t()` method.

Comment: Specify `activemodel` as a key? Just a wild guess.

Comment: Nope, it did not work.

Comment: Okay then. Meanwhile, I found [`ActiveModel::Translation` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html). That's more or less a clear path. It should already be included in `ActiveModel::Model`, it juts contains references to some methods to implement.

Comment: Great! Write an answer with what you did so others can find it.